# Export file common.po to other application

Tags: angular

I need to reuse common.po.ts (e2e test file) file functions in other applications. This file is in a lib, I exported it in public_api but it is not working in other projects.

export * from './lib/e2e/shared/common.po';

Comment: What does that file look like?

Comment: It's a file with strings and functions that i can reuse like this:   getLabelDropdownBySeletorCss(seletorElemento: string) {
    return this.getTextoElementoBySeletorCss(`${seletorElemento} ${CommonPo.SELETOR_DROPDOWN_LABEL}`);
  }